# Measuring roundness using buffers around centroids

Tags: buffer, area

I'm trying to measure the compactness (roundness) of some 800 polygons of different shape and size. I created the centroids and what I want to do now is to buffer those centroids with the exact same area of their polygons. 
Sorry if this is too simple but I just can't find the way to do it.

Comment: At what point exactly are you running into trouble? Also, what software/version are you using?

Comment: I don't know how/where to specify the size of the buffer based on the [area] field rather than in a distance.

Comment: Area = pi * r * r, r = sqrt(Area/pi)
But you should do more research into "roundness" and "compactness" for standards

Comment: look at the solution and comments in [Easily calculate “roundness/compactness” of a polygon](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/85820/2581)

Answer (score 0):

1. If not done already, calculate the area in a field for your polygons
2. Create centroids. Area field should carry over to the points.
3. Create and calculate a radius field that corresponds to a circle of the given area, for each point. The formula for circle area is A = pi*r^2, so r = Sqr(A/pi). Pi = 4*Atn(1). The exact VBScript field calculation is:

   Sqr ( [area]/(4*Atn(1) ) )
4. Run Buffer using the values in your radius field as the distance.