# Way to standardize building footprints

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a layer of building footprints that I would like to make each building outline the same size (all single family homes). Is there a way to batch convert all of the footprints (over 400) instead of replace each individually with a new feature?Attached is a screenshot of what I have thus far. [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating polygons as % of original area using ArcGIS Desktop?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73127/creating-polygons-as-of-original-area-using-arcgis-desktop)

Comment: Well I am just trying to have each footprint be the same size, this is not a duplicate.

Comment: What do you mean by 'same size': width, length, area, something else?

Comment: Correct, so I'd like all the building footprints to be the same size

Comment: Same width and length

Comment: If you just wanted to create rectangles of a certain dimension, it would be trivial. Maintaining the orientation is a bit more interesting....

Comment: Well I mean i would like it to keep the same orientation of each polygon aka whichever it is facing - is it possible?

Comment: Assuming that you want same area, then this is a duplicate because you merely de-buffer or buffer by a proportional amount to the extisting/desired area (and this will preserve the orientation)

Comment: Please use the [edit] button to try and make what you are asking clearer by revising your question.