# Selecting certain area of polygon according to size in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, select

I have a set of polygons with a certain size (3500 sq meters each for examples). I only need 3000 sq meters of every polygon.
Is there an automatic or semi-automatic way to create sub-polygons out of those polygons with the desired size ? 
Also, if indeed it's possible, is it possible to select from what side of the polygon you want to create the sub-polygon ?

Comment: Are your polygons all the same shape?  Or are we talking about a bunch of irregularly shaped Polygons?

Comment: They are quite different from one another

Comment: So, they are different shapes but all of them are exactly 3500 sq meters? And you want to arbitrarily extract a 3000 sq meter sample from each one?

Comment: This might be worth taking a look at.  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73127/creating-polygons-as-of-original-area-using-arcgis-desktop